# Operation 'restaurants.find()' buffering timed out after 10000ms at Timeout

Tags: javascript, react-native, mongoose, axios, connection-timeout

This is  my project structure:

```
▼ MyProject
    ► .expo
    ► node_modules
    ▼ backend     
        ► node_modules
        ► database
            database.js
        ▼ models
            Restaurant.js
            Category.js
        ► routes         
            ► api             
                CategoryRouter.js
                RestaurantRouter.js     
        .env     
        server.js     
        package-lock.json     
        package.json
    ▼ frontend
        ► assets
        ▼ components         
            CategoryItem.js         
            HomeHeader.js
            index.js
            RestaurantCard.js     
        ► constants
        ▼ screens
            Home.js
    App.js
    app.json
    babel.config.js
    package-lock.json
    package.json
```

This is `database.js`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const mongoURI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const dbName = process.env.DATABASE_NAME;

mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {
  dbName: dbName
});

const db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Mongoose connection error:', err);
});

db.once('open', () => {
  console.log('Connected to MongoDB via Mongoose');
});

module.exports = mongoose;
```

This is `RestaurantRouter.js`:

```
router.get('/restaurants', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Use Mongoose to find restaurants with the specified criteria
    const restaurants = await Restaurant.find({ registrationStatus: 'Active' })
      .sort({ averageRating: -1, numberOfReviews: -1 })
      .exec();

    console.log('Fetch successful');
    res.json(restaurants);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching restaurants:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});
```

And then I basically use axios in `Home.js`:

```
import axios from 'axios';
...

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      // Fetch restaurant data from your backend API using Axios
      const responseRestaurants = await axios.get('http://192.168.1.212:3000/api/restaurants');
      const dataRestaurants = responseRestaurants.data;
      setRestaurants(dataRestaurants);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Fetch error:', error);
    }
  }

  fetchData();
}, []);

...
```

When I run the application I get this error in the frontend:
`ERROR  Fetch error: [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500]`

And I get this error in the backend: `MongooseError: Operation 'restaurants.find()' buffering timed out after 10000ms at Timeout.<anonymous> (/Users/tbs/Projects/MyProjeck/backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:186:23) at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17) at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7)`

I've tried:

- Change DNS to 8.8.8.8
- .maxTimeMS(60000) to my restaurnat router

But I still get the same errors..